# Looking for a blur algorithm to emulate a camera positioned further away

Tags: photography

I am researching ways to blur images and for our purposes it seems that simple gaussian blur algorithms do not cut it.

We are looking for a way to take a high-resolution image and process it into an image that matches an image of the same object photographed from further away. I imagine there is some form of perspective transform that needs to be known, in addition to a blur.

Anyone know of resources or algorithms geared toward processing an image to look like a true optical blur rather than a gaussian?